# C - Finding Cube root of a number

Tags: c, double, decimal, math.h

In one of my assignments, I am supposed to get values of x^2, x^4 and cube root of x in which x is from 0 - 100. So far, I have this. (Testing with 5 numbers)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int powers(int n)
{
    return (n < 0) || (powers(n-1) && printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t\t%d\n", n, n*n, n*n*n*n, cbrt(n)));
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("number\tx^2\tx^4\t\tx^(1/3)\n");
    powers(5);

    return 0;
}
```

**MY OUTPUT**

```
number    x^2    x^4        x^(1/3)
0         0      0          0
1         1      1          0
2         4      16         -108170613
3         9      81         1225932534
4         16     256        -1522700739
5         25     625        -1124154156
```

So, my square and quatric are working as simple as it is but I cant get to work with cube root. When I do cube root separately it works.
`printf("Cube root of 125 is %f\n, cbrt(125));` yields `Cube root of 125 is 5.0000`.

I need help to why it does not work in my function. New to C programming so please be kind. **(*Compiler: Borland C++ and IDE: C-Free 5.0*)**

Comment: `cbrt` returns a `double`, so you should print the result with one of the floating-point formats: `%f`, `%g` or `%e`. Activate warnings to learn about such mismatches of printing formats and argument types.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo What header should I use?

Comment: @MOehm Ohmygod. IT WORKED.

Comment: you can use `pow(n, 1/3)`. Where `n` is a number.

Comment: Just as a comment... you should create functions for the calculations and don't create such long lines. It will make your code harder to read.

Comment: The C header for the math library is `<math.h>`. `<cmath>` is the same header, but for C++. It puts the functions into the `std`namespace. C doesn't have user-defined namespaces.

Comment: @MdMahfuzurRahman, `pow(n, 1/3)` returns 1.0 (try it).  `1/3` is integer division, so you've just written `pow(n, 0)` in an obfuscated manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `cbrt` accepts and returns a `float` or `double` value, which means that `cbrt(n)` will automatically convert `n` to a `float`/`double` before passing it to the function. The function will return a `float`/`double` but you are not storing it anywhere to force a conversion back to an `int`, you are directly passing it to `printf` specifying `%d` so the value is interpreted as an `int` even though it is actually a `float`/`double`.

A simple cast would be enough: `(int)cbrt(n)`, or you could use `%f` or `%g` specifier and print it as its real type.

Also storing in a temporary variable would lead to the same conversion behavior:

```
int v = cbrt(n);
printf("%d\n", v);
```

Comment: Oh alright, will just using `printf("%f\n", cbrt(n))` do the trick as `%f` takes a float?

Comment: @ImtiazRaqib: It's a bit more complicated than that: `printf` is a variadic function, and some arguments to such functions are "promoted". `char` and `short` are promoted to `int` and `float` is promoted to `double`. The upshot of this is that you can use `%f` and `%g` for both `float` and `double`. Activate warnings and let the compiler tell you about wrong formats.

Comment: @MOehm That makes a lot of sense. In my compiler they kept mentioning `promoted int to double` and I did not understand what it meant. Thank you.

Comment: `cbrt` has type `double` as input and output, not float. `cbrtf` works on floats.